# Possible lossy conversion from double to int

Tags: java, int, double, type-conversion

Why am I getting the `Possible lossy conversion from double to int` error and how can I fix it?

```
public class BinSearch {
    public static void main(String [] args)
    {
        double set[] = {-3,10,5,24,45.3,10.5};
        double l = set.length;
        double i, j, first, temp;
        System.out.print("Before it can be searched, this set of numbers must be sorted: ");
        for (i = l-1; i>0; i--)
        {
            first=0;
            for(j=1; j<=i; j++)
            {
                if(set[j] < set[first]) // location of error according to compiler
                {
                    first = j;
                }
                temp = set[first];
                set[first] = set[i];
                set[i] = temp;
            }
        }
    } 
}
```

As you can see, I've already tried replacing `int` with `double` near the top when declaring variables but it doesn't seem to do the job.

Comment: What do you think will happen when your `double` which can be, say `3.141`, is used to access an array index?

Comment: To be honest, I've really no idea :/.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change all your variables used as array indices from double to int (i.e. the variables `j`, `first`, `i`). Array indices are integer.

Comment: So I changed the datatype for `l = set.length;` and `i, j, first, temp;` to int but kept the `double` datatype as is.  It's now highlighting the `temp = set[first];` as a lossy conversion error.

Comment: @TigerLvr `temp` should stay double, since you assign to it values from your array of doubles.

Comment: I see.  I was also wondering, if you don't mind answering this, why, when attempting to print the unsorted array with `System.out.print("Before it can be searched, this set of numbers must be sorted: ");
        for(i=0; i<1; i++)
        {
            System.out.print(" " + set[i]);
        }` causes the output to be `-3.0` instead of `-3,10,5,24,45.3,10.5`

Comment: @TigerLvr Are you sure that the code you tried? I tried similar code and got `-3.0 10.0 5.0 24.0 45.3 10.5`?

Comment: I am sure. Could you tell me where you put that portion of code exactly?

Comment: @Tiger I just had the line that initializes the array followed by the loop that prints it.

Comment: @ Eran I'm still getting just -3.0 as an output.

Comment: @TigerLvr that's because you have i<1 condition in your loop. Should be i <set. length

Answer (score 1):

The array / loop indexes should be ints, not doubles.

When attempting to access `set[j]` for example, it complains about treating j as an int.

Answer (score 1):

Change the variable types as below. Array indices must be of type **int**.

```
public class BinSearch {
      public static void main(String [] args)
      {
          double set[] = {-3,10,5,24,45.3,10.5};
          int l = set.length;
          double temp;
          int i, j, first;
          System.out.print("Before it can be searched, this set of numbers must be sorted: ");
          for ( i = l-1; i>0; i--)
          {
              first=0;
              for(j=1; j<=i; j++)
          {
              if(set[j] < set[first])//location of error according to compiler
              {
                  first = j;
              }
              temp = set[first];
              set[first] = set[i];
              set[i] = temp;
          }
      }
  } 
}
```

Comment: Thank you. It seems to have stopped the error. Would you mind explaining to me why making `temp` a double stops the error from occurring?

Comment: The data type of "set" is double (64 bit value). When you assign it to temp, which is of type int(32 bit), a narrowing of types is happening. This is not implicitly possible.
You could have done it explicitly like this:  temp = (int )set[first];
Or, change the type of temp to double, so that it can accept a double value.