# Defining variable and using switches

Tags: java, variables

I have a problem to solve for my Java course but as I'm new to this language, I can't seem to find the solution. I'll be glad if someone can help me with this.

The problem is that `H` should be defined as `double`, because it may contain decimal values like `2.5`.

The current code works perfectly but only with whole numbers for `H`. I tried with `double H = 2.5;` but then all gets messed up. Also, I read about swithes from int to double and vice versa, tried some codes, but if I use switch it breakes `P1 * H` and `P2 * H`.

```
public class PoolTask {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        int V = 200;
        int P1 = 150;
        int P2 = 170;
        int H = 2;

        int P1w = P1 * H;
        int P2w = P2 * H;
        int Pt = P1w + P2w;

        if (Pt <= V) {

            int percentage1 = (Pt * 100 / V);
            int percentage2 = (P1w * 100 / Pt);
            int percentage3 = (P2w * 100 / Pt);

            System.out.println("The pool is " + percentage1 + "% full. Pipe 1: " + percentage2 + "%. Pipe 2: " + percentage3 + "%.");             
        } else if (Pt > V) {

            int liters = (Pt - V);

            System.out.println("For " + H + " hours the pool overflows with " + liters + " liters");
        } else {
            System.out.println("");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: change your variables: `H`, `P1w`, `P2w`, `Pt`, `percentage1`, `percentage2` and `percentage3` to `double`.

Comment: and `liters` as well

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Possible lossy conversion from double to int](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26413265/possible-lossy-conversion-from-double-to-int)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can convert all your variables to `double` like so:

```
class PoolTask {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        double V = 200;
        double P1 = 150;
        double P2 = 170;
        double H = 2.0;

        double P1w = P1 * H;
        double P2w = P2 * H;
        double Pt = P1w + P2w;

        if(Pt <= V) {
            double percentage1 = (Pt * 100 / V);
            double percentage2 = (P1w * 100 / Pt);
            double percentage3 = (P2w * 100 / Pt);
            System.out.println("The pool is " + percentage1 + "% full. Pipe 1: " + percentage2 + "%. Pipe 2: " + percentage3 + "%.");             
        } else if (Pt > V) {
            double liters = (Pt - V);
            System.out.println("For " + H + " hours the pool overflows with " + liters + " liters");
        } else {
            System.out.println("");
        }
    }
}
```

If however you do not want to display a variable with decimal values for example `percentage1` you can cast it to `int` in the print statement:

```
System.out.println("The pool is " + (int)percentage1 + ...)
```

Answer (score 2):

This is all because you are specifying the`double` datatype for H only. 
And after computation with other values when you save your result into a variable of type `int` the result loses its fractional part as you can't hold it for a variable of type `int`

Declare all of your variables of type `double` to get rid of the mess you're facing